# Ionic3 Tab bar is not clickable after use of Keyboard

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a huge problem. I am having a Login Page with two Input Fields and I have a tab bar with five Pages. The first page has a header with an image.

If I login and push the Tabbar page, the image in my header will hide after a second and the tab bar is not clickable anymore.

I have an image above the twi Input fields on my Login Page. If i remove the image (the input fields are online) it works. If i remove the inputs (image above is online) it works..

I have no idea what to do. I hate ionic. I think it is very very sad and stupid to work with it.